# Weblogic NullPointerException when trying to get new connection

Tags: java, jdbc, connection-pooling, weblogic12c

We are seeing below exception in production weblogic(ver 12) setup.
This happens randomly and no fix patter but it seems at times weblogic is throwing NPE when we try to get new connection,

Nested Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperFactory.getWrapper(JDBCWrapperFactory.java:146)
        at weblogic.jdbc.pool.Driver.allocateConnection(Driver.java:226)
        at weblogic.jdbc.pool.Driver.connect(Driver.java:156)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.getNonTxConnection(Driver.java:661)
        at weblogic.jdbc.jts.Driver.connect(Driver.java:128)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnectionInternal(RmiDataSource.java:588)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:545)
        at weblogic.jdbc.common.internal.RmiDataSource.getConnection(RmiDataSource.java:538)
        at MyOrg.jdbc.JdbcConnector.createNewConnection(JdbcConnector.java:1029)
        at MyOrg.jdbc.JdbcConnector.getConnection(JdbcConnector.java:933)

Just wanted to update that code to fetch connection is regular to get the connection from pool.
and this is working all through days, its only sometimes that we see above error, we are thinking of opening issue on Oracle, before that I was hoping if I could find some pointers from community here.

Comment: My suspicion would be that there is a deeper stacktrace here (eg inside a driver implementation)

Comment: There is no deeper stacktrace. deepest exception is NPE that is being originated from weblogic.jdbc.wrapper.JDBCWrapperFactory.getWrapper(JDBCWrapperFactory.java:146). there may be issue that WL layer is failing to connect with driver, though I am not able to understand any plausible reason.